# Display separated array-contents in separated lines

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with the php *sdk from Facbeook*. So i'd like to give out pages which the user is admin of. I'd decoded the json string to archieve an array (had already removed the "['data']"-key):

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Pagename1
            [id] => 1234567899011
            [about] => Sitedescription.
        )
    [1] => Array
    (
            [name] => Pagename2
            [id] => 1234567890
            [about] => Description of the page.
     )
 )
```

So, as you can see, i got an array which is seperated with int's from 0 upt to X. What i'd like to have is that i can output these values **foreach** array in one line like this example:

```
Pagname1, 1234567899011, Sitedescription

Pagename2, 1234567890, Description of the page

...
```

So i tried using different foreach variants, but i didn't get an useable result.

Does anyone know how i can realize this?

Comment: Tag `facebook` removed – this is not specific to developing for the FB platform, but just a general question about the basic handling of data structures.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 0, count = yourArray.length; i < count; i++ {
    console.log(yourArray[i].name + ', ' + yourArray[i].id + ', ' + yourArray[i].about);
}
```

PHP:

```
for ($i = 0, $count = count($yourArray); $i < $count; $i++ {
    echo $yourArray[$i]['name'] . ', ' . $yourArray[$i]['id'] . ', ' . $yourArray[$i]['about'] . "\n";
}
```

Not tested, but you should get the idea.

Comment: oh, my bad. i usually try to avoid php at all cost ;)